# Dynamic Angular Menu in MVC shared layout file

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC/Angular project. In the shared MVC _layout file I'm creating a UI menu based on JSON from a Web API call. I'm binding that data in the layout file using angular.

The issue I'm having is when I navigate to a new page MVC reloads the _layout file so the $scope.menu variable in the that file no longer exists so my UI menu disappears. The controller then calls the web API call again and repopulates everything so my UI menu is recreated.

Basically I need a way to keep my menu from being reloaded each time I navigate to a new page. Since I'm new to using angular and MVC together I'm not sure of the best approach. Is there a way to keep my $scope.menu variable from being removed when the shared _layout page is reloaded, can I store the JSON in in sessionStorage and recreate the $scope.menu so my UI menu doesn't disappear?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Angular code that creates the menu in the MVC shared _layout file.

<li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="item in menu" menu-item="item">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{item.Name}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
   <div class="dropdowncontainer">
   <div class="row" style="padding: 10px; height: 100%">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 no-float box-content right" ng-show="item.Places.length" style="height: 100%">
      <h4 style="vertical-align:top">Places</h4>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li ng-repeat="plc in item.Places"><a href="/report/{{plc.Name | removeSpaces}}">{{plc.Name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

//Controller that populates the menu with a web api call

mainModule.controller('navCtrl', function ($scope, dataService, modelService) {
if (!$scope.menu) {
    $scope.menu = modelService;

        dataService.getJson().then(
          function (res) {
              angular.copy(res.data, modelService);
          },
          function () {
              alert('Error Loading Navigation !');
          }
        );
    }
});

angular.module('main').value('modelService', []);

angular.module('main')
.factory('dataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
return {
    getJson: function () {
        return $http.get('web api call');
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: you could use sessionStorage, you could use cookies .. whaterver you feel more comfortable with (and depending on the size of your menu)